# Does there exist $k$ such that $2^k \equiv m(\mod p^n)$ when $\gcd (m,p^n)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p>2$ is a prime, $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd (m,p^n)=1$, is it true that there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k \equiv m(\mod p^n)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.
For all $k\in\mathbb N$ we have $2^k\not\equiv 3\pmod 7$.
In other words, $2$ is not a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) modulo $7$.

Your question is equivalent to ask if $2$ is a primitive root modulo each odd prime power.
This is not the case, as the example above shows.